# Decide if the edges of a mixed graph can be directed in order to be an Eulerian Graph

Tags: graphs, network-flow, eulerian-paths

I'm very stuck with this problem. Given $G = (V, E, A)$ a mixed graph where every edge in $E$ is directed and every edge in $A$ is undirected. Thinking as a max-flow problem, decide if it's possible to give a direction to every $a \in A$ in order to make $G$ an $eulerian$ graph.

The model I've thinking so far is to translate the problem as a matching problem. For every non directed edge, I would like to determine to which node this will point. For example, if $e=(u,v)$, from the vertex source there should be an edge connecting to $e$ and this one will be connected to $u$ and $v$. Every edge will have a flow capacity of 1, except for the edges of the target, which will have a capacity of $?$. I don't know if this model it's okay, but any clue (or another model) will help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want each node to have the same number of incoming and outgoing edges.

Let $\alpha(v)$ be the number of edges in $A$ outgoing in $v$ minus the number of edges in $A$ outgoing from $v$. Consider the graph $H=(V,E)$ and let $\delta(v)$ be the degree of $v$ in $H$.

We need to find an orientation of the edges in $H$ such that each vertex $v$ has an out-degree that is exactly its in-degree minus $\alpha(v)$.
In other words, if $k$ is the number of edges in $E$ that need to be oriented towards $v$, we must have:
$$
\delta(v) - k(v) = k(v) - \alpha(v),
$$
equivalently:
$$
k(v) = \frac{\delta(v) + \alpha(v)}{2},
$$
where we can assume that all $k(v)$s are non-negative integers and that $|E| = \sum_{v \in V} k(v)$ (otherwise there is no feasible orientation).

Create a graph $H' = (\{s,t\} \cup E \cup V, F)$ where $F$ contains the following directed edges:

- All edges in $\{s\} \times E$ with capacity $1$;
- An edge $(v,t)$ with capacity $k(v)$ for each in $v \in V$.
- Two edges $(e, u)$ and $(e, v)$, both of capacity $1$, for each $e \in E$.

Now compute a max flow $f$ from $s$ to $t$ in $H'$ and check whether its value $|f|$ is exactly $\sum_{v \in V} k(v)$.

If that's the case at least one valid orientation exists and it can be found by orienting $e = (u,v) \in E$ towards the unique endpoint $x \in \{u,v\}$ such that $f( \, (e,x) \, ) = 1$.

Comment: Didn't expect something so formal, thanks :)